Print punctuation after mandatory argument or after optional argument, but not after both
In traditional Catholic liturgical books, each day has a rank; most of these are straightforward and one or two words that never change. For those cases, I have a macro which takes no arguments, one for each rank, so that I conceal the formatting in my preamble and minimize the need for arguments in braces.
It gets trickier when I do have things that may change. I started with this macro and use it where the information changes.
\needspace{5\baselineskip}%
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
 {\centering{\textit{\large #1}}\par}%
}

So in my text I currently have \rank{Duplex I classis.} or \rank{Duplex I classis cum octava communi.} and so on.
I would like to simplify this to only type variable information between braces. However, I need a period to print at the end of the text, whether after the word "classis" or at the end of the optional argument, but not in both places.
MWE follows.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\input{commonheaders}

\usepackage{needspace}

\NewDocumentCommand{\duplexclassis}{mo}{%
\needspace{5\baselineskip}%
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
 {\centering{\textit{\large Duplex #1 classis #2}}\par}%
}


\begin{document}

\duplexclassis{I}[]

\duplexclassis{I}[Cum octava communi.]

\duplexclassis{II}[]

\end{document}

You can see that I manually inserted a period in the second example, but currently the period would print twice in that case if I included one after "classis" in the macro definition.

If I understand correctly you want a space and the optional argument if provided, then a full stop, so

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\input{commonheaders}

\usepackage{needspace}

\NewDocumentCommand{\duplexclassis}{mo}{%
\needspace{5\baselineskip}%
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
 {\centering\textit{\large Duplex #1 classis\IfValueT{#2}{ #2}.}\par}%
}


\begin{document}

\duplexclassis{I}

\duplexclassis{I}[Cum octava communi]

\duplexclassis{II}

\end{document}


Oh yes. A space is definitely needed if there’s an optional argument. Thanks for making that explicit — which I didn’t do in the post!
